# TCL read in a structured file and enter contents into an array

Tags: arrays, tcl

I am using TCL to read in a file of the form:

string1, 1.2 3.4

string2, 5.6 7.8

string3, etc...

The code needs to assume that the values of the key are not known in advance of reading in the file

I need the file to end up in an array in order to keep in sync with some other existing code.

I have tried

```
array set FileA
set libDir "/tmp/"

set Datafile [open $libDir\Data.csv RDONLY]

set DataFileB [split $Datafile "\n"]

foreach line $DatafileB {

    [lappend FileA [split $line ","]]

)

## also tried:

while {![eof $Datafile]} {
    set DatafileB [string trim [gets $Datafile]]
    puts -nonewline "'$DatafileB'"
    if {$DatafileB == {}} {continue}
    puts "EMFLimits contents are $DatafileB "
    set FileA [split $DatafileB ","]
    foreach {i j} $FileA {}
    set key $i
    set val $j
    set FileAurrents [split [gets [open $libDir\EFM_CurrentLimit.csv RDONLY]]]
    if {[info exists FileA($key)]} {
        lappend FileA($key) $val
    } else {
        set FileA($key) [list $val]
    }
    }
```

I keep getting an empty array?

I am quite new to TCL and have been tripped up on this simple puzzle for a few weeks now (in amongst other work too).

Comment: It looks to me like you never actually `read` the file. You open it, and then you split something apart into lines. Between those two statements, add `set contents [read $Datafile]`, and then use `$contents` in your `split` statement.

However, the second version looks like it should have worked... I'll assume your `Data.csv` actually has good stuff in it! 

Also... the file is in `/tmp` but then we use a back-slash in the filename? Kind of scary. Maybe use `file join $libDir Data.csv` to generate the file-name.  Are we certain that the `open` succeeded?

Sorry... rambling.

Comment: If it's an option, changing the file format so it's a valid tcl list/dict makes life a lot easier. `string1 {1.2 3.4} string2 {5.6 7.8}` etc. Then you can just read it and use `dict` commands.

Comment: That's an interesting foreach loop.   What were you expecting it to do?   I also think you need to look at your variable names.  Is `FileA` going to be an array or a temporary variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to fill an array with the contents of your file, then there are a few things wrong with both your attempts.

Your first attempt:

```
array set FileA    ;# This should have raised an error without the empty list
array set FileA {} ;# You can create a new array like this
set libDir "/tmp/"

set Datafile [open $libDir\Data.csv RDONLY]

set DataFileB [split $Datafile "\n"]  ;# open creates a channel for the file. If you do 
                                       # puts $Datafile, you will see something 
                                       # like file225721ca0b0 instead of the actual 
                                       # contents, so you won't get anything useful here

set fileContents [read $Datafile] ;# This gets all the contents of the file

close $Datafile                   ;# Closing a channel after use is a good practice

set DataFileB [split $fileContents "\n"] ;# And now we split

foreach line $DataFileB {             ;# Variable names are case sensitive. Be consistent
    [lappend FileA [split $line ","]] ;# You cannot use lappend on an array. In Tcl, there
                                       # is a difference between arrays and lists. 
                                       # lappend essentially stands for list append. 
                                       # This line should raise an error

    # You can use a bit of the code you used in your second attempt:
    foreach {i j} [split $line ","] {}
    set key $i
    set val $j
    if {[info exists FileA($key)]} {
        lappend FileA($key) $val
    } else {
        set FileA($key) [list $val]
    }
} ;# How did this become a parenthesis? It should be a brace

parray FileA   ;# You can use this to pretty print the contents of the array
```

As for your second attempt

```
while {![eof $Datafile]} {
    set DatafileB [string trim [gets $Datafile]]
    puts -nonewline "'$DatafileB'"
    if {$DatafileB == {}} {continue}
    puts "EMFLimits contents are $DatafileB "
    set line [split $DatafileB ","]  ;# FileA is an array you created. This line should 
                                      # raise an error because you are trying to overwrite 
                                      # the array with a "standard value". Use a different 
                                      # name. I will use line
    foreach {i j} $line {}
    set key $i
    set val $j
    set FileAurrents [split [gets [open $libDir\EFM_CurrentLimit.csv RDONLY]]] ;# You are 
            # not using this variable, so I don't know what you intend to do, but his line 
            # will continuously create new channels of the same file. You need to close 
            # channels after using them using close
    if {[info exists FileA($key)]} {
        lappend FileA($key) $val
    } else {
        set FileA($key) [list $val]
    }
}

close $Datafile
parray FileA
```

---

That said, I would probably write something more like this:

```
array set fileA {}
set libDir "tmp"
set dataFile [open [file join $libDir Data.csv] r]
set fileContents [read $dataFile]
close $dataFile

foreach line [split $fileContents "\n"] {
    lassign [split $line ","] key val
    lappend fileA($key) $val          ;# lappend creates the variable if it does not 
                                       # already exists so it is pretty convenient
}

parray fileA
```

---

You probably should do something similar with your other file and get another array, then compare the two, or whatever it is you are trying to do with the two files.

Comment: I would use `lassign` instead of `foreach` -- that is exactly what that command was designed for.

Comment: Note that `set contents [read $chan]; set lines [split $contents \n]` will result in a an empty last element of the list since the file data ends with a newline. I recommend `read -nonewline $chan`

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I had a look over the actual files, and I had used the {} at the end of the array assignment, and some of my other earlier attempts were fairly close. But your third option was spot on!